# DB2 unpivot convert columns to rows

Tags: db2, db2-luw, spring-mybatis

I'm asking this question with reference to the study material available at [How to convert columns to rows and rows to columns](http://www.dbatodba.com/db2/how-to-do/how-to-convert-columns-to-rows-and-rows-to-columns/). I have similar query explained in section UNPIVOTING. Here is my set up.
Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
    ID INTEGER, 
    CODE_1 VARCHAR, 
    CODE_2 VARCHAR, 
    CODE_3 VARCHAR, 
    CODE_1_DT DATE, 
    CODE_2_DT DATE, 
    CODE_3_DT DATE, 
    WHO COLUMNS
    );
```

Table Data

```
ID | CODE_1 | CODE_2 | CODE_3 | CODE_1_DT | CODE_2_DT | CODE_3_DT | UPDATED_BY 
1  | CD1    | CD2    | CD3    | 20100101  | 20160101  | 20170101  | USER1
2  | CD1    | CD2    | CD3    | 20100101  | 20160101  | 20170101  | USER2
3  | CD1    | CD2    | CD3    | 20100101  | 20160101  | 20170101  | USER3
```

My SQL to convert columns to row

```
SELECT Q.CODE, Q.CODE_DT FROM MYTABLE AS MT,
TABLE VALUES(
            (MT.CODE_1, MT.CODE_1_DT),
            (MT.CODE_2, MT.CODE_2_DT),
            (MT.CODE_3, MT.CODE_3_DT),
            ) AS Q(CODE, CODE_DT)
            WHERE MT.ID=1;
```

Expected output is

```
CODE | CODE_DT
CD1  | 20100101
CD2  | 20160101
CD3  | 20170101
```

I'm not able to get the expected result and getting error related to cardinality or cardinality multiplier. I don't know what's going wrong or sq. is correct...any pointers?

Comment: What version of DB2 are you using?  What's the actual error message?

Comment: **DB2 Version is 11 010 **
SQL Error [42601]: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLERRMC: ,;CARDINALITY OVER )
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLERRMC: ,;CARDINALITY OVER )

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select id1, code, date
  from mytable t,
       lateral (values (t.id, t.code_1, t.code_1_dt),
                       (t.id, t.code_2, t.code_2_dt),
                       (t.id, t.code_3, t.code_3_dt)
                ) as q (id1, code, date)
```

Comment: I changed sql but ended up error

SQL Error [42601]: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLERRMC: (;. <IDENTIFIER> JOIN INNER LEFT RIGHT FULL CROSS , HAVING GROUP
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLERRMC: (;. <IDENTIFIER> JOIN INNER LEFT RIGHT FULL CROSS , HAVING GROUP

Comment: It is tested and working in DB2 LUW 11.1 - what DB2 are you using?

Comment: I have DB2 Z/OS version 11 010. I think its not working on DB2 Z/OS. I have tested it on DB2 LUW and its working fine. Thanks for your help. Is there way to implement similar in DB2 Z/OS?
Note - SQL is working with LATERAL or TABLE in DB2 LUW.

Comment: Does your query have a comma before the table keyword? It is not shown in your question....

Comment: Yes, it dose. My bad, its typo in question. Updated Question accordingly, thanks.