# How to convert key-value pairs to column header and columns in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, pivot

I am trying to convert a table in my DB which looks like this:

| Key1 | Val1 | Key2 | Val2 | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id | 1 | Name | A | 1 |
| Id | 2 | Name | B | 1 |
| Id | 3 | Name | C | 1 |

to something that looks like this:

| Id | Name | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 3 | C | 1 |

I have implemented the logic in Python using Pandas but I'm having a very hard time doing the same in SQL.

Comment: DB2 <> SQL Server; what are you *actually* using?

Comment: I'm using DB2. Apologies, I added both just in case someone knows the way in SQL Server, I could try and replicate that for DB2.

Comment: [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423302/why-does-tagging-multiple-rdbms-products-make-my-question-unclear)

Comment: What would you need to get with the following rows for `(Key1, Key2)`: `(id, Name), (id2, Name), (id, Name2)`?

Comment: search for unpivot or check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216417/db2-unpivot-convert-columns-to-rows